# jQuery checkbox appears to be unchecked but it isn't

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes which I've styled using jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#check" ).button(); // ID of checkboxes (check0, check1, check2...)
    $( "#format" ).buttonset(); // ID of containing div
});
</script>
```

**THE PROBLEM:** Checkboxes are checked by default, but when I go ahead and uncheck some values, sometimes they still get POST-ed although visually it looks like I did the unchecking.

I tried this without CSS and noticed that sometimes when I click checkboxes really quickly one after another, they don't uncheck, although clicked.

That would be bearable, BUT when I switch CSS back on, they look unchecked, which is not true.

Anybody had this experience?

In shortest terms, it seems like sometimes click is registered by jQuery, and applied to checkbox styling - but the actual state of the checkbox is not changed.

EDIT: @Kamran Ali:  there's not much more code, checkboxes are generated dynamically, and I can't see them viewing browser source, here's how a checkbox looks in Firbug:

```
<label class="ui-state-active ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" for="check0" aria-pressed="true" role="button">
<span class="ui-button-text">Option 0</span>
</label>
```

Comment: please post your complete code for reference

Comment: have the same problem, did you find out the answer ?